# Link from Twitter breaking my site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, twitter

I have a tweet on Twitter that links to my site. It's http://www.rsguides.net . But whenever I click it, Heroku returns this:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/ host=www.rsguides.net fwd="98.116.187.155" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

and the site breaks for about two minutes before I am able to access it via normal, non-Twitter means.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the H12 error (Request Time Out) on Heroku
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout

An HTTP request took longer than 30 seconds to complete. In the example below, a Rails app takes 37 seconds to render the page; the HTTP router returns a 503 prior to Rails completing its request cycle, but the Rails process continues and the completion message shows after the router message.

Here is a link to help you resolve your time out issue.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Hope that helps..